# Is it possible to find the address of a non-primitive variable in Java?

Tags: java, object

If `Integer i = 88`, what is the memory address `i` resides at?

Additionally, if as part of Debugger, `id` number changes, is it indicative of the fact that a new object was created?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your second question is yes, the "id" you see in Eclipse's debugger uniquely identifies an object and so a change in it means a new object was created. So, for example:

```
Integer i = 55;
Integer j = new Integer(55);
Integer k = Integer.valueOf(55);
```

Here i and k will have the same id, since they refer to the same object; j will be different.

The memory address of one of these objects is not really a useful piece of information, since objects move around in memory. All you can know is that if i == k, they are the same object. (So here, i == k but i != j).

Answer (score 6):

Why would you need a memory address of any object in Java? All you can say is that `Integer` instance lies in heap. You cannot find the exact address.

Second question: yes, `Integer` objects are immutable, so when the value of a variable of type `Integer` changes it means it points to a different instance of `Integer`. However it doesn't necessarily mean a new instance was *created*. `new Integer(42)` always creates a new instance while `Integer.valueOf(42)` will create the same instance every time it is called.

Comment: Beside this, the address may be changing over time, as garbage collection moves objects to coalesce free space.

Comment: I have a question, how can it point to a different instance of `Integer` without that `Integer` being created first?

Comment: `Integer x = 42` is actually translated to `Integer x = Integer.valueOf(42)` - which *may* create a new instance or use cached one.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some one very close from JVM development team you cannot find out what type of data/address is stored in reference variable :) . All we need is access to the object residing in that reference and manipulate/execute it.

i am not sure about the second part of your question. Also, i cannot confirm if ID (in debugger) refers to java heap memory location.